# Inserting The Stripe Account ID Into My API Call

Tags: php, api

I am not an expert at coding. I was able to create a Connected account and save the connected account's id in my database. my question is how do I insert that connected account's id into my API calls.
below is where I need to insert that information:

```
$payment_intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
              'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
              'amount' => 3500,
              'currency' => 'usd',
              'application_fee_amount' => 1500,
              'transfer_data' => [
              //'plan' => 'plan_H30fBniUxmSPMh',
                'destination' => {{"CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID"}} // How do I insert my variable here******
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already save the Stripe Connect account id in you database then bring that ID using SELECT query and set database value in one variable.

that Stripe connect account id will be like `acc_***` that you stored in your database.

Here is an example :

```
$stripeAccountId = "acc_****"; //This should be coming from database in your case

$payment_intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
              'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
              'amount' => 3500,
              'currency' => 'usd',
              'application_fee_amount' => 1500,
              'transfer_data' => [
              //'plan' => 'plan_H30fBniUxmSPMh',
               'destination' => $stripeAccountId
```

as you can see in above code you can directly use that variable for the `destination` key.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. What you suggested worked, that is I am not getting error messages anymore. The problem was, I was putting the variable inside the curly brackets {{ $stripeAccountId  }}, so removing the brackets did the trick.

Comment: Yes, You don't need to write that variable inside the curly brackets and if you want to handle the error then keep your code inside the `try{..} catch () { ..}` that will help to handle the error throw by stripe in batter way,